# ParseJS, AngularJS user registration error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform

I am using AngularJS to create a user profile registration with a Parse Backend. However, on my console I am getting an error saying Parse is not defined. How would I be able to make it work and insert a new user into the database?

Below is my code:

```
 .controller('reg',['$scope',function($scope, $state, $rootScope){   


$scope.signUp = function() { 

  var user = new Parse.User(); 
  user.set("email", $scope.user.email); 
  user.set("password", $scope.user.password);
  user.set("firstname", $scope.user.firstname);
  user.set("lastname", $scope.user.lastname); 

  user.signUp(null, { 
      success: function(user) { 
        $rootScope.user = user; 
        $state.go('home'); 

      }, 
      error: function(user, error) { 
        alert("error here"); 

      }

  });

}; 

}])
```

Comment: have you added cdn of parse

Comment: @VRK, yes, i've added on my app.js file. is it also possible to do it within the controller?